# What is the point of compactness and how does it look visually?

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

I just learned what the term compact means, as in compact sets. I know what the definition of compactness is, but I don't get what the real significance of it is. How should I try to think of it in a visual way? Like for example, if I wanted to describe one-to-oneness I can draw a picture of $2$ circles and then an arrow from many points in the set to the other in a distrinct way to signify that an element from one circle goes to only one point in the other. Seeing that picture really drives the point home. How would I do the same for a concept of compactness?

**Edit** Just realized I also want to know what the point of compactness is as well. Why is this useful?

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^n$ the compact sets are precisely the sets that are closed and bounded. So a closed interval, or a union of two closed intervals, or a closed disk is a reasonable first image.

Comment: "Point": it simplifies many things, eg, in optimization, to show a continuous function is actually a homeomorphism, properties of one compact space carrying into another when linked by continuous functions. A long list; you probably will soon come across the first examples. It's a little like a big hammer when you get stuck without assuming it.

Comment: I sometimes think of compact sets as "essentially finite" sets, not in the sense of the points composing them, but in how they can be handled. A professional topologist might cringe maybe, but that's how I see them.